# Ruby: Selecting a set of array indices whose elements pass a test

Tags: ruby, arrays

Ruby has a `select` method that takes an array and returns a subarray consisting of all the elements that pass the test given in a block:

```
myarray.select{|e| mytest(e)}   #=> subarray of elements passing mytest
```

I am wondering whether there is a simple method to get not these elements, but their indices.  I understand you could do this:

```
indices = []
myarray.each_with_index{|e,i| indices << i if mytest(e)}
```

But I'm looking for a one-liner.  Does one exist?  Please don't write an extension to the Array class, I know you can get a one-liner that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another one-liner:

```
(0...myarray.length).select {|i| mytest(myarray[i])}
```

Cheers!

Comment: This one is king for its simplicity.  Can't believe I didn't think of this!  Well done.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner for you. It selects indexes of elements whose length is 3.

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', 't']
a.map.with_index{|el, i| i if el.length == 3}.compact # => [0, 1]
```

Or another one (suggested by @fl00r):

```
a.reduce([]){|ar,el| ar << a.index(el) if el.size == 3; ar}
```

Comment: `a.inject([]){|ar,el| ar << a.index(el) if el.size == 3; ar}`

Comment: I like this answer because it is a use of Enumerators, which are a non-obvious part of the language in my experience.

Comment: Good answers, I didn't know that with_index was its own method.

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
myarray.select{|e| mytest(e)}.map!{|e| myarray.index(e)}
```

However, this won't work properly if you have any repeated elements.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this one myself, but the repeated elements thing is very important.